# Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, output-formatting, warning-messages, faq

This is a really newbie question, but it has me confused. Why does this code **work without** `// MatrixForm` and **doesn't work with** `// MatrixForm`?

```
cov = {{0.02, -0.01}, {-0.01, 0.04}} // MatrixForm
W = {w1, w2}; FindMinimum[ W.cov.W, W]
```

The error is:

```
The function value ... is not a real number
```

Is `MatrixForm` supposed to be typesetting feature or it has other impact?

---

A similar problem appears here:

```
a = {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}};
inv = Inverse[a];
b = MatrixForm@{{0}, {0}, {0}, {1}};
soln = inv.b
```

[image]

Comment: From the `MoreInformation` section of `MatrixForm` in the docs: `MatrixForm` acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation.

Comment: @kguler and not all functions actually respect it, such as `MatrixExp`.

Comment: I also discuss this [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node174.html)

Comment: You may prefer to have your output rendered as `TraditionalForm`. You can do this easily from the preferences menu, Evaluation tab.

Comment: See also: [(44189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189/121)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`MatrixForm` is a wrapper that pretty-prints your matrices. When you do the following:

```
cov = {{0.02, -0.01}, {-0.01, 0.04}} // MatrixForm
```

you're assigning the prettified matrix to `cov` (i.e., wrapped inside a `MatrixForm`). This is not accepted as an input by most functions (perhaps all) that take matrix arguments. What you should be doing to actually assign the raw matrix to `cov`, yet get a pretty print in the output, is the following:

```
(cov = {{0.02, -0.01}, {-0.01, 0.04}}) // MatrixForm
```

You can also read more about why this happens due to the different precedences [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node174.html) in [Leonid's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) book.

---

You can also avoid having to use `MatrixForm` every time by setting the default display for matrix outputs to be typeset accordingly. For this, you set the [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PrePrint.html) variable in your `init.m` file as:

```
$PrePrint = Replace[# , mat_?MatrixQ :> MatrixForm[mat]] &
```

You can also find this in [Szabolcs's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) [mathematica tricks](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php). To reset the value of `$PrePrint`, simply unset it with `$PrePrint=.`

Comment: You could also set the format type for output cells to traditional form.

Comment: I am guilty here because wrapping matrices by `MatrixForm` when they're inside object such as `Image` or `Graph` will break the formatting of that object.

Comment: @Szabolcs the link to your "mathematica tricks" page is now broken

Answer (score 25):

While the question has been more than answered there are still some things that seem to me worth adding. The first is that, in my opinion, `MatrixForm` is "essentially" obsolete. If you wish your matrices always look like matrices (in the output) you can set the format type of output cells to `TraditionalForm` (use the Appearance tab in the Preferences menu). In fact, you can also set the format type of your input cells to `TraditionalForm`, although you have to be a little careful if you do that (doing that is not recommended by WRI but it has some well known supporters...).

Alternatively you can use the `ConvertTo` menu to convert any matrices to `TraditionalForm` while keeping other cells or expressions in `StandardForm` (if you prefer that). The keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>.  Finally, if you would like all your matrices always to appear in `MatrixForm` and avoid these evaluation problems, you can evaluate at the beginning of your Mathematica session

```
$Post = If[MatrixQ[#], MatrixForm[#], #] &
```

or you can put it into an init file and have it evaluate automatically. (Of course you can use `TraditionalForm` in place of `MatrixForm`).

Coming back to the issue of `TraditionalForm` vs `MatrixForm` for matrices: the only problem I can see with using the former is that it looks "too nice" so that if the rest of your output is in `StandardForm` the style of your matrices will not match the rest of your output. But other than that I can't think of any use for `MatrixForm`.

Comment: Thanks. This was useful information to know. So exactly, how does this `$Post = If[MatrixQ[#], MatrixForm[#], #] &` works internally or in general? Because it let's the kernel know of some preliminary settings before you actually start creating `List` to do computations on, correct. And Mathematica will know what to do with the result (in terms of how you want it to be outputted to the screen).

Answer (score 16):

[`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html) is a function to prettyprint matrices and cannot be used in computations. Just leave the [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html) away and you're fine:

```
a = {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}};
inv = Inverse[a];
b = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {1}};
soln = inv.b
```

> ```
> {{-(1/2)}, {0}, {1/2}, {1/2}}
> ```

If you want that result displayed (!) in a nice readable way, you can of course use [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html) again:

```
soln // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  -\frac{1}{2} \\
>  0 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} \\
>  \frac{1}{2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thanks. Was always wondering why it always did that. I just turned to a calculator if it was a big complicated system. But now I wanted to figure out why so I can do it in mathematica.

Comment: Of course `MatrixForm` (like all formatting functions) is special in that it is *stripped away* from the output stored in `Out` if it is applied top-level (but *only* in that case). This may cause the wrong impression that it has no effect on calculation, but only on display.

Answer (score 16):

David's answer is correct and the one you need to solve your specific problem. I thought nonetheless that it is worth providing some additional information that might help explain how to diagnose similar issues.

Matrix/tensor operations like `Dot` and `Inverse` are designed to work with *lists*, that is, expressions with a `Head` of `List`. It also works with `SparseArray` objects. From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dot.html):

> When its arguments are not lists or sparse arrays, `Dot` remains unevaluated.

You can check whether your expressions have compatible `Head`s using [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html). It is common for people to use postfix (`//`) notation to check this. As you can see, in your version of the code, `a` has head `List` while `b` has head `MatrixForm`. So they can't combine.

```
a//FullForm
```

> `List[List[1,0,1,0],List[2,1,1,1],List[1,2,1,0],List[0,1,1,1]]`

```
b//FullForm
```

> `MatrixForm[List[List[0],List[0],List[0],List[1]]]`

If you discover you have erroneously created a matrix wrapped in `MatrixForm`, you can change it back to a list using `First`.

```
FullForm[First[b]]
```

> `List[List[0],List[0],List[0],List[1]]`

As an aside, I don't see any point assigning the variable `inv` to represent the `Inverse` of `a`. Unless your real problem uses $a'$ more than once (especially if it is expensive to calculate), you can just as easily do:

`Inverse[a].(First@b)`

Note that I have mixed using of `@` and `[]` style notation for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: Thank You! This was very pleasing to read. I like to read something and it physically makes since (in terms of how the kernel internally deciphers computations) and learn different ways to implement the same task, while also making it robust and more efficient without defining extra variables unnecessarily. +1 `:)`