# Option pricing with the Black-Scholes model. Code not running

Tags: mathematical-optimization, finance

```
(*initialisation of variables*)
n = 10;(*expected value greater than 3*)
r = 0.03;
σ = 0.2;
sMax = 2;
sMin = -2;

(*define Δx.*)
Δx = (sMax - sMin)/(n - 1);

(*adding vector matrix... any assignment of v value should be 
included here*)
vecMatrix = Array[v, n];

(*reusable internal variables*)
p = 0.5 (σ^2)/(Δx^2);
q = (2 r - (σ^2))/Δx;

x = (2 p + r) - 0.75 q;
y = 5 p + q;
a = p - 0.25 q;
b = -2 p - r;
c = p + 0.25 q;

(*introducing matC for one time initialisation*)
matC = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {n, n}, n - 1] -> x, 
    Band[{1, 2}, {n, n}, {n - 1, n - 3}] -> y, 
    Band[{2, 1}, {n - 1, n}] -> a, Band[{2, 2}, {n - 1, n}] -> b, 
    Band[{2, 3}, {n - 1, n}] -> c}, {n, n}];
 MatrixForm [matC]*
 MatrixForm[vecMatrix]
```

Comment: Can someone help to debug,,it is not running,and i am not able to put the boundary conditions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Perhaps you could explain your problem somewhat better.

Comment: Probably related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations

Comment: Welcome, @user3005. Please understand that pasting a swathe of code with "it doesn't work" doesn't make it easy for people to help you. The problem is probably that you are multiplying not using `Dot` (`.`) and you wrapped the lists in `MatrixForm` before multiplying. See the question I linked previously.

Comment: You are aware of the `FinancialDerivative` function, new in version 8, are you?

Comment: I thought tht posting the code can help to understand my problem,,anyway,how can i help more in order to get more help from u guys??In fact i have the code in matlab which works great,,my only problems is with mathematica!!!
can sm1 help:???

Comment: @user3005 yes, posting the code is important, but we need to know more than just "it doesn't work". What error messages are you getting? Are you running from a freshly launched kernel? What output are you expecting? Have a look at some other questions on the site, especially those with at least 5 votes, and you will see how to write a question that shows a problem clearly. By the way, comments can be at least this long so you don't need to write in SMS speak.

Answer (score 6):

I've done a lot of option pricing with MMA, but I can't relate your code to plain old Black-Scholes:

```
d1[spot_,strike_,ir_,div_,vol_, T_] = (Log[spot/strike] + (ir-div+vol^2/2) T) / (vol T^0.5]);  
d2[spot_,strike_,ir_,div_,vol_, T_] = (Log[spot/strike] + (ir-div-vol^2/2) T) / (vol T^0.5]);
N[z_] = (1 + Erf[z/Sqrt[2]])/2 ; (*cumulative normal density*)

bsCall[spot_,strike_,ir_,div_,vol_,T_] :=
   spot*E^(-div*T)*N[d1[spot,strike,ir,div,vol, T]] - 
   strike*E^(-r*T)*N[d2spot,strike,ir,div,vol,T]]
```

where

```
ir = interest rate  
div=dividends paid  
vol=volatility of the stock as measured by the standard deviation of its price
T = time to expiry  
Log[] = the natural logarithm
```

(I added this simple stuff to help others understand your question.)  I don't see where the Black-Scholes part comes into your code? It would help educate others if you put your question in a context, for example, black-scholes option pricing is easy if you have one option, but if you have 100,000 at varying strikes, etc.  But your question seems to really be about matrix algebra and sparce arrays.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. In fact it is more on ''code for pricing an European option under Black–Scholes model using ETD with central discretisation''. I have been introduced to the concept of boundaries in option pricing but i have no idea how to include it in the code.

Comment: I wouldn't use capital `N` in your function definition, as it is a built-in one. Also, using `n[z_]=CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z]` would arguably yield a slightly better readable and more generalizable version of your definition.

Comment: @Sjoerd I actually used an italicized N in my code, along with other symbols that don't show well here, but didn't want to clutter my comment. I didn't know about CDF[] when I wrote this code.  I just copied. I should look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in the last line. I suspect you mean:

```
matC.vecMatrix // MatrixForm
```

which yields:

```
0.19875 v[1]+0.55125 v[2]
0.09 v[1]-0.2325 v[2]+0.1125 v[3]
0.09 v[2]-0.2325 v[3]+0.1125 v[4]
0.09 v[3]-0.2325 v[4]+0.1125 v[5]
0.09 v[4]-0.2325 v[5]+0.1125 v[6]
0.09 v[5]-0.2325 v[6]+0.1125 v[7]
0.09 v[6]-0.2325 v[7]+0.1125 v[8]
0.09 v[7]-0.2325 v[8]+0.1125 v[9]
0.09 v[8]-0.2325 v[9]+0.1125 v[10]
0.55125 v[9]+0.19875 v[10]
```

As an aside, comments that just say `(* define \[Delta] x *)` aren't that helpful to the next person looking at the code. I would recommend using commenting to explain what the variables are for.

As a further comment on your code, all your variables are global to your session, so the comment "reusable internal variables" is misleading. If you want to scope variables as internal to a particular calculation, you need to use scoping constructs like `Module`, `Block` and `With`. You might find [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/8) helpful.

Comment: "As an aside, comments that just say `(* define \[Delta] x *)` aren't that helpful to the next person looking at the code. I would recommend using commenting to explain what the variables are for." -  ["Good comments don't repeat the code or explain it. They clarify its intent. Comments should explain, at a higher level of abstraction than the code, what you're trying to do."](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=3JfE7TGUwvgC&pg=PT1094)

Answer (score 1):

Write down the Black-Scholes equation in the following way

```
TraditionalForm[BS = {-(r*c[t, s]) + r*s*D[c[t, s], {s}] + (1/2)*s^2*\[Sigma]^2*D[c[t, s], 
{s, 2}] + D[c[t, s], {t}] == 0, c[T, s] == Max[s - k, 0]}]
```

which will spit out the Latex-like form that, in turn, can be solved analytically as follows

```
DSolve[BS, c[t, s], {t, s}][[1]]
(dsol = c[t, s] /. DSolve[BS, c[t, s], {t, s}][[1]]) // TraditionalForm
```

which gives you the analytical solution of the Black-Scholes model

$\frac{1}{2} e^{-r T} \left(\frac{s e^{r T} \left(\text{erfc} \left(2 k \log +\left(2 r+\sigma ^2\right) (t-T)-2 (s \log )\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \sigma  \sqrt{T-t}}-\frac{k e^{r t} \left(\text{erfc} \left(2 k \log +\left(2 r-\sigma ^2\right) (t-T)-2 (s \log )\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \sigma  \sqrt{T-t}}\right)$

Mind that **dsol** is our analytical solution here.

For our conditions we will use the obtained above solution to get the price of the call option, for example

```
NumberForm[dsol /. {t -> 0, s -> 100, k -> 100., \[Sigma] -> 0.2, T -> 1,r -> 0.05}, 16]
```

resulting

```
10.45058357218558
```

To make the plot for the above conditions

```
t = 0; k = 100; \[Sigma] = 0.2; T = 1; r = 0.05;

Plot3D[1/
2 E^(-r T) (-E^(r t)
   k Erfc[((t - T) (2 r - \[Sigma]^2) + 2 Log[k] - 2 Log[s])/(
  2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-t + T] \[Sigma])] + 
E^(r T) s Erfc[((t - T) (2 r + \[Sigma]^2) + 2 Log[k] - 
   2 Log[s])/(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-t + T] \[Sigma])]),
    {t, 0.01, 1}, {s, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
AxesLabel -> {"T-t", "S", "C"}, LabelStyle -> Larger, 
ImageSize -> 600, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[y*28/29]]]
```

[image]

If you need numerical solutions and explanations, look at https://lucynowacki.github.io/blog/method-of-lines-for-black-scholes-explicit/index.html or if you need code in Mathematica, touch me.

You can also solve the BS numerically. The simplest is the Explicit Finite Difference method as follows

```
K=100.; S0=100.; r=0.05; sig=0.2; T=12/12.; M=300; Nt=4000; 
Smax=220.;
n=Range[1,M-1];
dt=N[T/Nt];
ds=Smax/M//N;
U=ConstantArray[0.,{M+1,Nt+1}];
Sgrid = Range[0, Smax, ds];
Tgrid=Range[T,0,-dt];
(*boundary conditions*)
U[[1,All]]=0.;
U[[-1,All]]=Smax- K E^(-r*Tgrid);
U[[All,-1]]= Max[#-K,0]& /@ Sgrid; (*terminal condition*)
(*coefficients for finite difference matrix*)
\[Alpha] = 0.5*dt*(sig^2*n^2-r*n);
\[Beta] = 1-dt*(sig^2*n^2+r);
\[Gamma] = 0.5*dt*(sig^2*n^2+r*n);
(*set up the finite difference matrix*)
L = Table[KroneckerDelta[n,m](1-dt* 
(sig^2*n^2+r))+KroneckerDelta[n+1,m](0.5*dt* 
(sig^2*n^2+r*n))+KroneckerDelta[n-1,m](0.5*dt*(sig^2*n^2-r*n)), 
{n,1,M-1}, {m,1,M-1}];
Max[Abs[Eigenvalues[L]]] (*must be less than 1 for stability*)
offsetConstants = {\[Alpha][[1]], \[Gamma][[-1]]}; (* offsets to 
accomodate boundary conditions*)
(*to populate finite difference matrix with numerical solution*)
Do[ U[[2;;-2,it]] = L . U[[2;;-2, it+1]];
U[[{2,-2},it]] = U[[{2,-2},it]]+ 
offsetConstants*U[[{1,-1},it+1]],
{it,Nt,1,-1}]
Print["The call price is: 
",Interpolation[Thread[{Sgrid,U[[All,1]]}],S0]]
```

To plot the solution matrix

```
ListPlot3D[Transpose[U],ColorFunction->Hue, PlotRange-> 
{{0,100},All,{0,15}},DataRange->{{0,Smax},{0,1}},AspectRatio->1, 
LabelStyle -> Larger]
```

[image]

Note that here the solution matrix is transposed; however, it is irrelevant.