# Why isn't the matrix product computed?

Tags: matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

I have the following input:

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/11/15/geogebra4.png

Why is the matrix not computed, giving me a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: Remove the `// MatrixForm` and report back...

Comment: Okay, it works now. I thought that `// MatrixForm` would just change the output, not the internal representation?