# Inverting a matrix

Tags: matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

I am facing a strange behaviour from Mathematica when asking it to invert the following matrix:

```
m = {{a, b, b, 0, 0, 0}, {b, a, b, 0, 0, 0}, {b, b, a, 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, c, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, c, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c}} // MatrixForm

Inverse[m] // MatrixForm
```

It doesn't output the inverse of the matrix but just the command I entered. But, knowing that my matrix is bloc diagonal, when I enter each one of the blocs separately it does compute their inverses. Where is the trick?

Comment: try removing the `//MatrixForm` in the definition of `m`

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/61 perhaps...

Comment: or add braces `(m={{a..},..})//MatrixForm`

Comment: @cormullion, Thanks, I figured there must be one, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Probably shouldn't invert matrices anyway, it makes them dizzy.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau try sleeping on them instead

Comment: @cormullion No thanks, I'm more the Cauchy type.