# How can you convert a matrix back into a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

It is very simple in Mathematica to convert a list of lists into a matrix: all you need to do is apply the `//MatrixForm` function to it and voila.

Is it possible to do the reverse though? I have a matrix that I want to convert back into a list of lists, so as to manipulate its elements more easily. Is this possible? Is there a '`ListForm`' function that deletes all `MatrixForm`s from the element in question?

As an example, here is the `FullForm` for one of my elements:
`MatrixForm[List[List[63],List[4,62]]]`

Is there a function which would take this as input and return simply `List[List[63],List[4,62]]`?

Thank you

Comment: You should go through [this section of the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html).  The things covered there are essential for using Mathematica, and will also answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

Comment: [Link to W Community version](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/210661)

Comment: another approach to maintaining your underlying data structure but still using `MatrixForm` for display is to enclose in brackets ()s e.g. `(x={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}})//MatrixForm`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll start with the standard warning: `MatrixForm` is [just a wrapper](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/5) that makes your matrices look pretty. Nothing more, nothing less. It does not "convert" a list of lists to a matrix. Your list of lists is already a matrix:

```
m = Identity@10;
MatrixQ@m
(* True *)
```

Using `MatrixForm` wrapped matrices in calculations will only give you an error. Use it only for typesetting/display purposes.

---

To answer your specific question, if you have a `MatrixForm` wrapped around it for whatever reason, you can remove the wrapper in one of the following ways:

```
First@m (* or *)
Identity @@ m (* or *)
m /. MatrixForm[x_] :> x
```

which will give you back the list of lists.

Comment: Why not `First`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Heh, [why not indeed!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) :) I'll add it in.

Comment: While we´re at it, why not `m[[1]]`?