# Mysterious behaviour of Plot

Tags: plotting

I'm a little mystified as to the behaviour of Plot. In one case below I am directly executing on a list element. In the other I am (I think) doing exactly the same thing.

[image: screenshot]

```
{\!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"0.8428052992418218`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"2.9498185473463763`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"10.376841190414979`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"18.567556607671506`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"19.835589895411935`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"12.785737509119585`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"5.056824588888251`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"0.17818628606314801`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.623652001221018`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.766226907641884`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.35643726605216447`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"1.833259838113068`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"2.8302784917279467`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"2.379191319891826`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"0.000018895233526195646`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.00006613331734168476`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"7.050073190254268`*^-6", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.00018295847632984757`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.02188974160496609`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.15805063754244977`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.5622288462589179`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"0.00008075374690358442`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.0002826381141625455`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.006395977611793048`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.015283348744076256`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.019300390555482223`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.11119144385377162`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.4715749018628204`", " ", "x"}], "+", 
      "0.9999999999999999`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"2.7481113699184277`*^-6", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"9.618389794714496`*^-6", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.00016708892041431852`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.00044176827552258255`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.01300177132742992`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.10505076553843518`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.45836833608337313`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"0.00006827623743710186`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.00023896683102985652`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.0017602742919764405`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.004998102807515743`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.021156532004700534`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.08814761576991853`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.41987525779948176`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"0.023487877236053424`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.08220757032618699`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.4204788526870417`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.8456782059021367`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.9216087821424758`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.7028387524746703`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"1.1856144547716247`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\), \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"0.00025723275547461085`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "7"]}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.000900314644161138`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "6"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.00004607105199456746`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "5"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.002135608980416426`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "4"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.08484600384284115`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "3"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0003167605382352677`", " ", 
SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"0.025169829012923813`", " ", "x"}], "+", "1.`"}],
TraditionalForm],
TraditionalForm,
Editable->True]\)}

Plot[ -0.842805 x^7 + 2.94982 x^6 - 10.3768 x^5 + 18.5676 x^4 - 
  19.8356 x^3 + 12.7857 x^2 - 5.05682 x + 1. , {x, -2, 2}]
Plot[ gsols[[1]], {x, -2, 2} ]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully.  It appears that you have `TraditionalForm` wrapped around every single expression in that list.  If you get rid of `TraditionalForm`, it should work.  Appears to be the same situation as here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations

Comment: It does work, but now for every x first the complete list gsols is evaluated and of that only the first element element is used for the plotting. For efficiency, I would prefer Plot[gsols[[1]]//Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}]

Comment: Is there a simple way to remove all the TraditionalForm wrapping? I don't honestly know how my equations got contaminated with that in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Input gsols=Table[...] may be labeled with TraditionalForm (or any other cell). If you now set the cell back to StandardForm the output should be accordingly. Not sure about the removing of the TraditionalForm wrapping at output... otherwise start your calcs in a fresh notebook an avoid TraditionalForm.

[image]

Comment: Well, I could help, thanks for the acceptance!