# How to make Mathematica show matrices and vectors nicely

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, vector

It shows me like `{{0}, {1}, {0}, {-1}}` . Is it possible to make it look like a vector, always?

Comment: `MatrixForm` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I know about matrixform, but I dont want to type it everytime.

Comment: Two different users provided a `$PrePrint` solution in this Q&A: [(3098)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/121).  Perhaps this question should be close as a duplicate of that more elaborate one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I also thought to flag it for this, but this one actually is a really different question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your notebook or init file

```
    $PrePrint = If[MatrixQ[#], MatrixForm[#], #] &;
```

Then all matrices will automatically display as `MatrixForm`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to format lists as column vectors also, try

```
$PrePrint = 
  Which[MatrixQ[#], MatrixForm[#], VectorQ[#], ColumnForm[#], 
    True, #] &;
```

Now also

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

As @kattern pointed out, `MatrixForm` will pretty print your lists to look like matrices.

```
{{0}, {1}, {0}, {-1}} // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A word of caution, however: `MatrixForm` **can get in the way of your calculations** if you are not careful. See this question and the related answers: [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/27951).

For instance, you could get bitten by something like this:

```
matWRONG = {{0}, {1}, {0}, {-1}} // MatrixForm
(matCORRECT = {{0}, {1}, {0}, {-1}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both expressions print out a nice formatted version of your vector, but there is a subtle difference.

- In the first case, you assigned the graphical output of `MatrixForm`, i.e. the pretty-printed form, to the variable `matWRONG`. That's probably not what you meant to do.
- The second version assigns the vector to the `matCORRECT` variable, then pretty-prints the value of that variable. The variable itself contains the vector, and can be further operated upon.

For instance, you can transpose the `matCORRECT` vector, but if you try to do the same on the `matWRONG` one, Transpose will not recognize its input as a vector and return unevaluated, and you will probably be confused.

```
Transpose[matCORRECT]
Transpose[matWRONG]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: would the macro he wrote cause any problems like this?

Comment: @grdgfgr As far as I know, it won't. In my understanding, in that case the pretty-printing will happen "last", i.e. after the assignments etc have already been taken care of.