# Creating Matrix,Inverted and Upper Triangulate inside Module

Tags: matrix, inverse, input

I was trying to fit this into a module but I didn't have any luck. And for some reason it won't Inverse the Matrix. 
Here's the code:

Input:

```
f[x_, y_] = 2^x - y
n = 3
m = Array[f, {n, n}]
k = MatrixForm[m]
Inverse[k]
MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[m]]
```

Output:

[image: Output]

And here is how the output should look like :

[image]

Is it possible to put this into a Module function?
Please help!

Comment: Look up `Transpose[]`.

Comment: You shouldn't use the output of `MatrixForm` to carry out further calculations (see: [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/27951)). This is the reason why your `Inverse` was returned unevaluated. If you had tried `Inverse[m]` instead, you would have seen `Matrix {{1,0,-1},{3,2,1},{7,6,5}} is singular.` which would have been a lot more informative to you.

Comment: @MarcoB I updated my answer with your comment (if you don't mind), this is the correct answer indeed.

Comment: @Bichoy Of course, thanks for including it.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I actually meant to use Transpose[](@Guesswhoitis.) and not Inverse[]. Anyway is there a way to implement this into a module, all of it?
`f[x_, y_] = 2^x - y | 

n = 3

m = Array[f, {n, n}] |

MatrixForm[m] |

Transpose[m] // MatrixForm |

MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[m]] |`

Comment: Ok guys nevermind @Bichoy Helped me do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by MarcoB in the comments, one shouldn't use `MatrixForm` for calculations (check [the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations) he referred to). As he suggested, this is the real reason `Inverse` doesn't evaluate.

Also, in this case the matrix `m` is singular.
You can easily check that by `MatrixRank[m]` which yields `2`, and also by checking `Det[m]==0`.

How to proceed with `m` being singular highly depends on what you are trying to do next with `Inverse[m]`.

Comment: (Thanks for the correction Chris)

Comment: Ok thanks very much I did it! Only now to implement it into a module.
`f[x_, y_] = 2^x - y | n = 3 m = Array[f, {n, n}] | MatrixForm[m] | Transpose[m] // MatrixForm | MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[m]] |`

Comment: Then, just put the whole thing into a module, something like: `Module[{f,n=3,m}, f[x_,y_] = 2^x -y; m=Array[f,{n,n}]; .... ]`. This module will return the value of the last statement being evaluated (but don't terminate the last statement inside with `;` )

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I did it. It finally works like it should.

Comment: You are very welcome @Andrej