# How to compute the partial trace of a 4x4 matrix?

Tags: matrix, summation, products

I want to compute a partial trace using formula

$\rho_A=\sum\langle B|\rho_{AB}|B\rangle$ .

Example,

$\rho_{AB}= $$
\begin{pmatrix}
a &  b  & c & d\\
e  & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m  & n & o & p
\end{pmatrix}
$

I try to evaluate

```
MatrixForm[
 Sum[
   TensorProduct[{{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}}, (q*r)], 
   {1, 2}]]
```

but Mathematica returns the expression unevaluated.

The output is wrong. I am not sure whether the operator should be `TensorProduct` or `Cross`.

I expected to get

$\rho_{A}= $$
\begin{pmatrix}
a +f  & c+h\\
i+n & k+p\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: Not familiar with partial trace, but does [this package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5571/) help?

Comment: Thank you again. Finally. I know. I explore it first

Comment: Your expression for `Sum` is ill-formed.

Comment: I will check it .tq]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example can be achieved using `Map` with a level specification, `Partition` to generate the sub-matrices and `Tr` to calculate the traces.

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p]
r = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};

Map[Tr, Partition[r, {2, 2}], {2}]
```

> {{a + f, c + h}, {i + n, k + p}}

Comment: I dont get the same value

Comment: Do you mean that evaluating the expressions above don't give you the same result?

Comment: yes. but i change the r in term in matriks,  may you explain the command Map, Tr, Partition work ? tq

Comment: I'm guessing that this [Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098) may help you.  To learn how this works try experimenting, e.g. evaluate `Partition[r, {2, 2}]` on its own and perhaps something like `Map[dummy, Partition[r, {2, 2}], {2}]` and read the documentation for these functions.

Comment: thank you very much MikeLimaOscar

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by partitioning your matrix and performing a tensor contraction. To be clear, having:
$$ \rho_{AB} = \sum_{ijkl} \rho_{ij}^{kl} | ij \rangle \langle kl |$$
the partial trace over $B$ may be defined as:
$$ \mathrm{tr}_B \rho_{AB} = \sum_{jl} |j\rangle \langle l|  \sum_m \rho_{mj}^{ml}, $$
which is a tensor contraction. You have written $\rho$ as a matrix (or a two-indexed tensor), so first you need to partition it:

```
rhop = ArrayReshape[rho, {2, 2, 2, 2}];
```

Now `rhop[[i,j,k,l]]` will give you $\rho_{ij}^{kl}$.
Then the tensor contraction is easily done by Mathematica's libraries:

```
rhoc = TensorContract[rhop, {2, 4}]; rhoc//TeXForm
```

This yields
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a+f & c+h \\ i+n & k+p \\\end{array}\right). $$
Similarly, if you wanted to take the partial trace over $A$, you just need to contract the first indices:

```
rhod = TensorContract[rhop, {1, 3}]; rhod // TeXForm
```

Which returns:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}  a+k & b+l \\  e+o & f+p \\ \end{array} \right). $$

Note that using `Partition` yields a slightly different tensor than `ArrayReshape`, but you can convert one in another by performing a `TensorTranspose` over the indices 2 and 3.