# Partial trace and Partial Transposition of a matrix easily?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, operators

Could someone help me to understand as to how to compute the partial trace and partial-transposition of an arbitrary matrix? I mean, is there any code to carry out these operations in Mathematica?

EDIT: Using the code suggested by @Budha_the_Scientist, following error messages appear:

```
`In[29]:= mat = {{1, 2}, {3, 0}};

In[30]:= partialtrace[a_List?MatrixQ, dim_, sys_] := 
 Module[{mat, gtb, i, j}, mat = Partition[a, {dim[[2]], dim[[2]]}];
  If[sys == 1, gtb = Tr[mat, Plus, 2], 
   gtb = Table[Tr[mat[[i, j]]], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[1]]}]];
  normalize[gtb]]

normalize[a_List?MatrixQ] := a/Tr[a]

partialtranspose[a_List?MatrixQ, dim_, sys_] := 
 Module[{mat, pt}, mat = Partition[a, {dim[[2]], dim[[2]]}];
  If[sys == 1, pt = ArrayFlatten[Transpose[mat]], 
   pt = ArrayFlatten[
     Table[Transpose[mat[[i, j]]], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[1]]}]]];
  Return[pt];]

In[33]:= partialtrace[mat, {2, 2}, 2]

During evaluation of In[33]:= Part::partw: Part 2 of {{{1,2},{3,0}}} does not exist. >>

During evaluation of In[33]:= Part::partw: Part 2 of {{{{1,2},{3,0}}}} does not exist. >>

During evaluation of In[33]:= Part::partw: Part 2 of {{{{1,2},{3,0}}}} does not exist. >>

During evaluation of In[33]:= General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[33]= {{1/(1 + Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[2, 2]]]), 
  Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[1, 2]]]/(
  1 + Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[2, 2]]])}, {Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[2,
     1]]]/(1 + Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[2, 2]]]), 
  Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[2, 2]]]/(
  1 + Tr[{{{{1, 2}, {3, 0}}}}[[2, 2]]])}}`
```

Comment: Can you explain these terms? Perhaps include a link to a definition?

Answer (score 3):

I used to do those things years ago and I have a code which is supposed to be working but please check it and tell me if it is really correct:

```
partialtrace[a_List?MatrixQ, dim_, sys_] :=
   Module[{mat, gtb, i, j},
      mat = Partition[a, {dim[[2]], dim[[2]]}];
      If[
          sys == 1 , gtb = Tr[mat, Plus, 2] , 
   gtb = Table[Tr[mat[[i, j]]], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[1]]}]
         ];
      normalize[gtb]
    ]

normalize[a_List?MatrixQ] := a/Tr[a]

partialtranspose[a_List?MatrixQ, dim_, sys_] :=
   Module[{mat, pt},
    mat = Partition[a, {dim[[2]], dim[[2]]}];
      If[
          sys == 1 , pt = ArrayFlatten[Transpose[mat]] , 
   pt = ArrayFlatten[
     Table[Transpose[mat[[i, j]]], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[1]]}]]
          ];
         Return[pt];
    ]
```

The first parameters of the functions is the matrix that you want to work on, the second element is the dimension of the each subspace for example `{2,2}` and the third element is the subspace that is traced or transposed either `1` or `2`.

I think I have initially took them from a quantum information package and then changed them slightly.

**EDIT:**
By the way it seems you haven't searched the SE enough because there are also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139977/how-to-efficiently-compute-the-partial-trace-of-a-matrix?rq=1) and [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119148/how-to-compute-the-partial-trace-of-a-4x4-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1) which can be useful.

Comment: Thanks, @Buddha_the_Scientist. It would be nice if you could post an example to better understand the various notations in your code.

Comment: For example you have a composite system comprised of $2$ dimensional subsystems which corresponds to the density matrix: `mat`, and then you want to trace over the second system then you use the command `partialtrace[mat,{2,2},2]`

Comment: @user59583  Please can you show me how to use `partialtranspose` in case of a system comprised of three qubits?