# Symbolic determinant is not computing

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to compute the determinant of a symbolic matrix made with the following code:

```
NewMatrix[n_] := Module[{i = 1, j = 1, M = Array[m, {n + 1, n + 1}]},
  For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= n + 1, j++,
    If[j < i, m[i, j] = a[[j]],
     If[j == i, m[i, j] = x,
      If[j > i, m[i, j] = a[[j - 1]], 0]]]
    ]
   ]; M // MatrixForm]
```

But when I apply:

```
Det[NewMatrix[4]]
```

Mathematica returns this:

[image]

If I try to give a and x numerical values it still doesn't show the numerical value of the determinant, just gives the same expression but with numbers. What is happening here?

Comment: Your output, `NewMatrix[4]`, is in the `MatrixForm`, while `Det` can be applied to `List`s; first, remove the `//MatrixForm` part and it will work. However, I'm getting an error: `Part::partd: "Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object."`

Comment: Regarding the error: insert also `a = Array[a, n]` into the `Module`, after `i` and `j`, and before `M`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not include [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) in the definition of `NewMatrix`; wrappers are only used for display. Also use an indexed variable rather than using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) for `a`.

```
Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n]

NewMatrix[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[
  {i = 1, j = 1, M = Array[m, {n + 1, n + 1}]},
  For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= n + 1, j++,
    If[j < i, m[i, j] = a[j],
     If[j == i, m[i, j] = x,
      If[j > i, m[i, j] = a[j - 1], 0]]]]]; M]

NewMatrix[4] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Det[NewMatrix[4]]
```

[image]

```
% // Simplify
```

[image]

```
detNewMatrix[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[
  {arr = Array[a, n]},
  (x + Total[arr])*(Times @@ (x - arr))]
```

Verifying that this is the determinant

```
And @@ Table[detNewMatrix[n] == Det[NewMatrix[n]] // 
  Simplify, {n, 10}]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `a` is (going to be) a vector, since you index it with [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).  In that case, here is a simpler way:

```
newMatrix[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  With[{v = Array[Indexed[a, #] &, n]},
   Table[Insert[v, x, i], {i, n + 1}]];

mat = newMatrix[4];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Det[mat] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can inject a vector for `a` using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
mat /. a -> {1, 12, 23, 34}
% // MatrixForm
(*
  {{x, 1, 12, 23, 34},
   {1, x, 12, 23, 34},
   {1, 12, x, 23, 34},
   {1, 12, 23, x, 34},
   {1, 12, 23, 34, x}}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations) for answers to why `MatrixForm` messes up the computation.

For more [alternatives to `For` loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Alternatives+to+For+loop), see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/4999) or search the site.