# Convergent matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, homework

I had a question where they ask me if a matrix is convergent. Matrix is as below:

```
A = {{-1.7, -12.6, -12.6}, {-1.2, -5.6, -6.6}, {1.5, 7.8, 8.8}}
```

I put it in matrix form:

```
MatrixForm[A]
```

And used the command:

```
MatrixPower[A, n]
```

With increasingly big n until I got (at n=100 000, with I believe is enough to see convergence)

```
{{-2.84217*10^-14, -1.13687*10^-13, -1.42109*10^-13}, {-1., -4., \
-5.}, {1., 4., 5.}}
```

So I wrote that the matrix was not convergent for its first row, and convergent to {-1, -4, -5} for row 2, and convergent towards {1, 4, 5} for row 3. And it is incorrect.

I even tried:
MatrixPower[A, n]
Limit[n->Infinity] but it did not work either.

Comment: Your `MatrixForm` does nothing for your calculation. It merely displays A  as a matrix. It does not alter A.

Comment: Yes, sure, I just wrote down all the stuff I was doing with the problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the correct way to write your final command

```
MatrixPower[A, n] // Limit[#, n -> Infinity] &
```

And the result is

```
{{-3.20081*10^-14, -1.28033*10^-13, -1.60041*10^-13}, 
 {-1., -4., -5.}, 
 {1., 4., 5.}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Konstantinos. But you agree that it converges to -1,-4,-5 and 1,4,5?

Comment: It seems so. I don't understand why you said that the first row is not converging though. It seems that it does I think to some small numbers.

Comment: It's my fault... I thought that the first row was not convergent since it looked so weird compared to row 2 and 3!
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Don't mention it. Cheers!!!