# Solve vs Reduce and use of parameters

Tags: equation-solving

i'm new in the world of mathematica. i have a simple problem : i want to find a  solution of a system of equations. The problems are:

1) Is it better to use **Solve or Reduce** (for this kind of situation)?

2) I've problem with the (known) **parameters** of these equations ( f_1 , f_2).

Let's see the matter:

the code is ( here there is a screen more clear because the subscripts make trouble):

[[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jm1Y.png)]

```
Reduce[{(1/Sqrt[V (Subscript[Z, 1] *Subscript[Z, 2]*Subscript[Z, 3] - 
             V*MU)]) == (Subscript[f, 1]*Subscript[f, 2])^(-1/2),Sqrt[(Subscript[Z, 1] *Subscript[Z, 2]*Subscript[Z, 3] - V*MU)/
          V] Subscript[Z, 1]^-1 == (Subscript[f, 1]/Subscript[f, 2])^(
       1/2), Sqrt[(Subscript[Z, 1] *Subscript[Z, 2]*Subscript[Z, 3] - 
            V*MU)/V] Subscript[Z, 
        2]^-1 == (Subscript[f, 2]/Subscript[f, 1])^(1/2), 
      Sqrt[(Subscript[Z, 1] *Subscript[Z, 2]*Subscript[Z, 3] - V*MU)/
          V] Subscript[Z, 3]^-1 == (Subscript[f, 1]*Subscript[f, 2])^(
       1/2), ((Subscript[Z, 1] *Subscript[Z, 2]*Subscript[Z, 3] - V*MU)^(
         3/2)/(V^(3/2)*Subscript[Z, 1] *Subscript[Z, 2]*Subscript[Z, 
           3]) ) == (Subscript[f, 1]*Subscript[f, 2])^(1/2), MU == 0}, {V,
       Subscript[Z, 1] , Subscript[Z, 2], Subscript[Z, 3], MU}, Reals]
```

- I have fixed the parameters to be positive but i obtain two conditional expressions associated to two values.
- If you see it finds the value of Z_1 but it doesn't substitute its value into Z_3.

Thank you.

Comment: How much of this question is covered by: [Solve vs Reduce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17127/5478)?

Comment: The subscripts will make debugging harder; reserve them only for display purposes.

Comment: @Kuba I have written in the problem list if for this kind of situation is better Reduce or solve

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Before the stuff of the code there is the screeshot of the code which is the link called "code".

Comment: As I already said: the subscripts certainly look pretty, but they will make algebraic manipulation a pain. Regarding your use of `MatrixForm[]`, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098).

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I made a mistake : the old screen was related to another thing, now there is the correct one. I'm so sorry