# An error of unequal length when using Transpose[y]?

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, warning-messages

Why do I get this error? I just clicked shift+enter in the `y` and it appeared.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAKs8.png

This is the data

```
y = {{4.9176, 5.0208, 4.5429, 4.5573, 5.0597, 3.8910, 5.8980, 5.6039, 
5.8282, 5.3003, 6.2712, 5.9592, 5.0500, 8.2464, 6.6969, 7.7841, 
9.0384, 5.9894, 7.5422, 8.7951, 6.0831, 8.3607, 8.1400, 9.1416}};

x = {25.9, 29.5, 27.9, 25.9, 29.9, 29.9, 30.9, 28.9, 35.9, 31.5, 31, 
30.9, 30, 36.9, 41.9, 40.5, 43.9, 37.5, 37.9, 44.5, 37.9, 38.9, 
36.9, 45.8};
Id = IdentityMatrix[24];
x = MatrixForm[Thread[{1, x}]];
M = x*Inverse[Transpose[x]*x]*Transpose[x];


SSE = Transpose[y]*(Id - M)*y

SST = Transpose[y - Mean[y]]*(y - Mean[y])
```

I just wanted the transpose of `y` (first, in the end I want to know `SSE`).

How come *unequal length* error appeared?

Help me please

(I apologize for many questions)

Comment: Please post actual code rather than pictures of code.  You'll likely get more help that way.

Comment: @JimB Oh ok sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: remove `MatrixForm` from the rhs of definition: use `x = Thread[{1,x}];`

Comment: @JimB I did it.

Comment: @kglr I did it but the error its still there, though it says something different

Comment: You'll need to use `.` rather than `*` for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Among several other issues with your code things: [Don't use `MatrixForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html):

```
ClearAll[x, y]
y = {{4.9176, 5.0208, 4.5429, 4.5573, 5.0597, 3.8910, 5.8980, 5.6039, 
    5.8282, 5.3003, 6.2712, 5.9592, 5.0500, 8.2464, 6.6969, 7.7841, 
    9.0384, 5.9894, 7.5422, 8.7951, 6.0831, 8.3607, 8.1400, 9.1416}};
x = {25.9, 29.5, 27.9, 25.9, 29.9, 29.9, 30.9, 28.9, 35.9, 31.5, 31, 
   30.9, 30, 36.9, 41.9, 40.5, 43.9, 37.5, 37.9, 44.5, 37.9, 38.9, 
   36.9, 45.8};

x = Thread[{1, x}];
y = y[[1]];
Id = IdentityMatrix[24];
M = x. Inverse[Transpose[x] . x] . Transpose[x];
SSE = y . (Id - M) . y
```

> 13.392961097651924

```
SST = (y - Mean[y]).(y - Mean[y])
```

> 57.56312745333333`

Comment: Thank you kglr, I have a question why do you add y = y[[1]]; ?

Comment: Oh and you also removed the IdentityMatrix line, is y = y[[1]]; somehow equivalent to?

Comment: @user459663, forgot to paste the line with `Id =...`. Re `y[[1]]`, we need a `T` by 1 vector for the dependent variable.

Comment: I don't understand. Is `Transpose[y - Mean[y]].(y - Mean[y])` equivalent to `(y - Mean[y]).(y - Mean[y])` + `y = y[[1]];` ?

Comment: @user459663, they are not .  You need the latter to get the sse in mathematica. Btw, mathematica does not distinguish between column and row vectors.

Comment: ok so that's why you removed Transpose from `Transpose[y - Mean[y]].(y - Mean[y])` right?

Comment: Though I still don't get the line $y=y[[1]];$

Comment: @user459663, it is to remove the extra braces `{{...}}` in your original definition of `y = {{ ...}}`.

Comment: oh ok, I tested your code with other different data for x's and y's and just when I clicked shift+enter in y=y[[1]] this error pop up "Nonrectangular tensor encountered."

Comment: @user459663,  (1) you need `y=y[[1]]` only when `y` is defined as `y={{...}}` (For example, in the picture in your other question this is not the case so you don't need to use `y= y[[1]]`).  (2) you need to use `ClearAll[x,y]` before the lines that define `x` and `y` .

Comment: mmh that's so strange I did it all and now gives like million of vectors

Comment: wait..I got it, the Identity matrix had different size..