# Change of basis in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to set up a change of basis matrix from the base V -> W with the *RowReduce* function that's built into Mathematica. I am then supposed to verify the result by taking the product of the change of basis matrix and multiplying it with the co-ordinate vector for x. You can see the Bases and the vector x below.

So, my question is, how do I setup the change of basis matrix and then verify it, with just the *RowReduce* function? Thanks in advance.

```
V = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}}
W = {{4, 6}, {2, 5}} 

x = {6, 6}
```

Comment: Pleeeease. Don't use `MatrixForm` in computations. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/38178) why. Moreover, it would be appreciated if you would post copyable Mathematica code instead of images.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'll edit the post then :)

Answer (score 5):

This might give you an idea... I merge `V` and `W` into one matrix with `ArrayFlatten` and apply Gaussian elimination by `RowReduce`.

```
V = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}};
W = {{4, 6}, {2, 5}};
B = RowReduce[ArrayFlatten[{{V, W}}]][[All, 3 ;;]]
V.B == W
```

> {{-3, -(7/2)}, {7/3, 19/6}}
>
> True

Comment: Ah, smart. Wasn't thinking about how you could compare the two functions that easily. Just one question though. What does the ArrayFlatten, and the [[All, 3 ;;]] commands mean? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten` can merge block matrices to a single matrix. And `A[[All, 3 ;;]]` reads off the columns `3` to `Dimensions[A][[2]]` of a matrix `A`. See the documentation of `Part` and `Span` for details.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thank you so much. If i were to calculate the change of basis matrix from W -> V, using the Inverse function, would I first take the inverse of W, and then multiply W^1 * V?

Comment: You're welcome. I'd rather use `V.Inverse[W]` or `W.Inverse[V]` depending on which direction you would like to have.

Comment: Well, I'd like to know the change of basis matrix from the base W -> V, so how would the function look like?

Comment: Hmm. It is not entirely clear to me what you look for. If you are looking for a matrix `A` such that `A.W == V`, then `A = V.Inverse[W]` is what you want (just multiply the equation with `Inverse[W]` from the right). If you seek `B` such that `B.V == W`, then `B = W.Inverse[V]`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to be more clear. English is not my primarylanguage so forgive me for any misunderstandings. First, with your help, I decided the change of basis matrix from the bases V -> W, and after that I verified it so that it'd be correct. Now, I'm trying to decide the change of basis matrix from W -> V instead.

Comment: The basis change matrix W -> V should be the inverse of the basis change matrix V -> W.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87559/discussion-between-wznd-and-henrik-schumacher).