# Elements Replacement

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

Please I need help on how to replace elements in a matrix with another elements. For example, I have a (5,5) matrix, and I like to replace elements from All rows and column 3 to 5, with zero. such that (All, 3;;5) replace with zero.

m = MatrixForm[Partition[Range[25]^2, 5]]

[image: Sample Matrix]

I like to replace all the elements in the specified area with zero:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `MatrixForm` when defining the matrix. It's only a display wrapper, as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations).

```
m = Partition[Range[25]^2, 5]
```

> {{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}, {36, 49, 64, 81, 100}, {121, 144, 169, 196, 225}, {256, 289, 324, 361, 400}, {441, 484, 529, 576, 625}}

Replacement:

```
m[[All, 3 ;; 5]] = 0;
m
```

> {{1, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {36, 49, 0, 0, 0}, {121, 144, 0, 0, 0}, {256, 289, 0, 0, 0}, {441, 484, 0, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 2):

```
m = Partition[Range[25]^2, 5]
```

A few more alternatives:

```
SparseArray[m[[All,  ;; 2]], Dimensions[m]]
PadRight[m[[All, ;; 2]], Dimensions@m]
MapAt[0 &, m , {All, 3 ;; }]
```

all give

> {{1, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {36, 49, 0, 0, 0}, {121, 144, 0, 0, 0}, {256, 289, 
>     0, 0, 0}, {441, 484, 0, 0, 0}}