# Setting Some Elements in a Matrix to zero

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

Assuming I have the a 5x7 matrix below:
b = ((1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 4, 2), (36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 5, 1), (121, 144, 
    169, 196, 225, 8, 9), (256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 9, 5), (441, 484, 
    529, 576, 625, 3, 7))
I want to set some elements on each row and different column to zero. such that, I will have: 
b[[(Row1, column 2;;3 and column 5;;7),(Row2, column 1;;2 and column 4;;7),(Row3, column 1;;4 and column 6;;7),(Row4, column 2;;3 and column 6;;7),(Row5, column 1;;4 and column 6;;7)]]=0

Comment: duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191658/elements-replacement

Comment: When posting questions use proper Mathematica syntax. For example, in the example definition of `b`, you should have used `List` brackets rather than parentheses. This would help others help you, since they could then copy and paste the data into a notebook without having to manually edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = {{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 4, 2}, {36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 5, 1}, {121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 8, 9}, 
    {256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 9, 5}, {441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 3, 7}};
cols = {{2 ;; 3, 5 ;; 7}, {1 ;; 2, 4 ;; 7}, {1 ;; 4, 6 ;; 7}, 
    {2 ;; 3, 6 ;; 7}, {1 ;; 4, 6 ;; 7}};
```

You can use `MapAt`:

```
pos = MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, cols];

b2 = MapAt[0 &, b, Join @@ pos];
TeXForm[Row[MatrixForm /@ {b, b2}]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 4 & 9 & 16 & 25 & 4 & 2 \\
>  36 & 49 & 64 & 81 & 100 & 5 & 1 \\
>  121 & 144 & 169 & 196 & 225 & 8 & 9 \\
>  256 & 289 & 324 & 361 & 400 & 9 & 5 \\
>  441 & 484 & 529 & 576 & 625 & 3 & 7 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 64 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 225 & 0 & 0 \\
>  256 & 0 & 0 & 361 & 400 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 625 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, you can use `SparseArray`:

```
keep = Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, 
   Complement[Range@Dimensions[b][[2]], #] & /@ Join @@@ (cols /. Span -> Range)]

b3 = SparseArray[keep -> Extract[b, keep], Dimensions[b]];
```

or `ReplacePart`:

```
inds = Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, Join @@@ (cols /. Span -> Range)];
b4 = ReplacePart[b, inds -> 0]
```

or `Part` assignment inside `Do` or `Table` or `MapIndexed`:

```
b5 = b;
Do[b5[[## & @@ i]] = 0, {i, inds}]

b6 = b;
Table[b6[[## & @@ i]] = 0, {i, inds}];

cols2 = Join @@@ (cols /. Span -> Range);
b7 = b;
MapIndexed[(b7[[#2[[1]], #]] = 0) &, cols2];

b2 == b3 == b4 == b5 == b6 == b7
```

> True