# Constructing a special square matrix

Tags: matrix

I am trying to define an $n \times n$ matrix for even $n$ using

```
d1 = 
 Table[
   Which[
     i < j, 0, i == j, i!/(2^i 0! i!), 
     EvenQ[i - j] && j == 0, (i)!/(2^i (i/2)! j!), 
     EvenQ[i - j] && OddQ[i], (i)!/(2^i ((i + 1)/2 - 1)! j!), 
     EvenQ[i - j] && EvenQ[i], (i)!/(2^i (i/2 - 1)! j!), 
     True, 0], 
   {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]
```

Is my code correct? Will it be correct when $n$ is odd?

[image]

Comment: Probably you don't need a separate case for `j==0`.  Also, is there are additional `j` dependencies in the other two cases (I don't know, because I don't know exactly what you are trying to do).  What happens when `n` is odd?

Comment: Dear mjw, I added both cases even and odd...thanks

Comment: Okay, so `i` is the row, and `j` is the column, right?  The term's dependence on `j` (other than whether it zero or not) is the `j!` in the denominator, yes?

Comment: Dear mjw, I row, j column,....yes...

Comment: I am not sure that you would need a special case for `j==0`.  Wouldn't it just follow the pattern also?  Try `n=4`.  Is this what you want (a few 3/4 over there in the lower left corner)?

Comment: Dear mjw, I not sure if what I did is correct or not, that is why I need help...thanks

Comment: Why not `EvenQ[i - j], (i)!/(2^i (i/2)! j!), True, 0]` ?

Comment: How should we interpret the image you show? Is it the output are now getting or the output you *want* to get?

Comment: Also, don't use `N` as a variable. `N` is a reserved symbol for a built-in function.

Comment: Dear m_goldberg, N taking the values 2,4,6,8.....even,or 1,3,5,7,9...odd

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could mention the book/paper/anything where these matrices are discussed.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you state what exactly is the `{i,j}` entry of each matrix.

Comment: I suggest using `SparseArray` and `Band`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for both even and odd $N$=`n`. Notice that the generated matrix is actually $(N+1)\times(N+1)$ as the indices run from 0 to $N$. You can see this in your images, which show an even-sized matrix for odd $N$ and vice-versa.

```
M[n_Integer /; n >= 0] :=
  SparseArray[{{i_,j_} /; EvenQ[i-j] && i>=j -> (i-1)!/(2^(i-1)((i-j)/2)!(j-1)!)},
    {n + 1, n + 1}]
```

If you need a non-sparse matrix, use [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html).

I'm not sure why the bottom-right matrix element in your odd-$N$ image is zero. Shouldn't it be $2^{-N}$ as it lies on the diagonal?

Comment: Or use `// MatrixForm` to view the matrix.

Comment: Dear all, many thanks for all comments, I will check and back...best regards

Comment: Many thanks Roman, you solved my problem, thanks mjw

Answer (score 1):

```
d1[n_] := Table[
            Which[i < j, 0,EvenQ[i - j], (i)!/(2^i ((i-j)/2)! j!), True, 0], 
                  {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}
               ]
```

The output seems to be what you want.  Here are a couple of examples:

`d1[3] // MatrixForm`:

[image]

`d1[4] // MatrixForm`:

[image]

Comment: This is not the matrix from the images. In yours, element (3,1) is $3/8$ whereas in the original it is $3/4$.

Comment: Defining a matrix with `MatrixForm` is not a good idea as it interferes with subsequent calculations and confuses beginners.

Comment: You are right about the 3/4 vs 3/8.  I"ll look at it again when I have some time.

Comment: Defining a matrix with `MatrixForm`...  I did not know about the interference, please elaborate.  I am also a beginner!

Comment: `MatrixForm` is only a display wrapper, like `InputForm` and `TeXForm` etc. If you define `A={{1,1},{1,1}}//MatrixForm` then a call like `Eigenvalues[A]` will fail because it is interpreted as `Eigenvalues[MatrixForm[{{1,1},{1,1}}]]` instead of `Eigenvalues[{{1,1},{1,1}}]`. Use `MatrixForm` only to display a matrix, not to define it. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations

Comment: Yes, great point!  I used `MatrixForm` here because I wanted to display the matrix.  But you are right, I didn't consider later calculations.  Edited use of `MatrixForm` to reflect your advice.  Also, I've edited my answer after looking more carefully at the output.  It's consistent with my point the other day that we only need one line to define the function.  The 'one line' also ends up very similar to your definition (but with a different indexing).  I guess there really is only one way (up to indexing) to define it.