# constructing Matrix from coefficients of solution & assigning 0 for empty Cells

Tags: matrix, replacement, coefficients

**i tried to construct a matrix from the coefficients of my solution, but problem that;**

**1; how can i get coefficients out of Solve**

**2; some Matrix elements are empty so i must assign 0 in those empty cells. and that's why it doesn't construct matrix directly by MatrixForm.**

look at Code after Sol input**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

n = 4; 
m = 0.145; 

Subscript[x, 0][t_] = 0;
 "Those two initial condition make some cells empty that's why i can't directly construct a matrix using matrixform"
Subscript[x, n + 1][t_] = 0; 

Subscript[k, (j_)?EvenQ] = 1.7; 
Subscript[k, (j_)?OddQ] = 5; 
Subscript[k, 0] = 1; 
Subscript[k, n + 1] = 1; 

ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := 
   (1/2)*Sum[Subscript[k, j]*(Subscript[x, j - 1][t] - Subscript[x, j][t])^2, 
     {j, 1, n + 1}]; 

te[x_, t_, n_] := (1/2)*m*Sum[Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t]^2, {j, 1, n}]; 

lg[x_, t_, k_, n_] := te[x, t, n] - ue[x, t, k, n]; 

eq[x_, t_, k_, n_] := Expand[EulerEquations[lg[x, t, k, n], 
     Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {j, 1, n}], t]]; 


sol = Simplify[MatrixForm[Solve[eq[x, t, k, n], Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[x, j]][t], 
      {j, 1, n}]]]]
```

" I Tried these down with all ways never give me coefficients alone so i put them in a matrix i just need the number with no x[t] or x''[t]"

```
rules = CoefficientRules[lst[j], {Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[x, j]][t], {j, 1, n}]}]

matr = CoefficientArrays[lst, Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[x, j]][t], {j, 1, n}]]

lst = List @@ sol
```

Comment: There are many issues with your code. First of all, the use of `Subscript`s isn't recommended. Secondly, you are trying to use `CoefficientRules` and `CoefficientArrays` on `lst` before it's even defined. Furthermore, it seems like `lst` is a `List`, and yet inside `CoefficientRules`, you are using `lst[j]` when likely it should be `lst[[j]]`. Unfortunately, Mathematica.SE is not a debugging service, so unless you can focus on a specific issue with *Mathematica* that you are having, it's difficult to help. Also, perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i will edit my question sir. thanks

Comment: Don't use `MatrixForm` to define matrices, it is only a display wrapper and interferes with calculations. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get the `sol` without `MatrixForm` with

```
sol = Simplify[Solve[eq[x,t,k,n], Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[x, j]][t], {j, 1, n}]]]
```

you can get the matrix of coefficients with

```
matr = D[Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[x, j]][t], {j, 1, n}] /. First[sol],
  {Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {j, 1, n}]}]
```

> {{-46.2069, 11.7241, 0, 0}, {11.7241, -46.2069, 34.4828, 0}, {0, 34.4828, -46.2069, 11.7241}, {0, 0, 11.7241, -18.6207}}

The first part of this is how you get the solutions out of `Solve`:

```
Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[x, j]][t], {j, 1, n}] /. First[sol]
```

> $$
> \left\{11.7241 x_2(t)-46.2069 x_1(t),11.7241 x_1(t)-46.2069 x_2(t)+34.4828 x_3(t),34.4828x_2(t)-46.2069 x_3(t)+11.7241 x_4(t),11.7241 x_3(t)-18.6207 x_4(t)\right\}
> $$

The second part is taking the first derivative with respect to each one of the $x_j(t)$ in order to get the matrix of coefficients.

Finally, if you want to look at `matr` in a pretty form, you can use `MatrixForm` as a display wrapper:

```
MatrixForm[matr]
```

> $$
> \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  -46.2069 & 11.7241 & 0 & 0 \\
>  11.7241 & -46.2069 & 34.4828 & 0 \\
>  0 & 34.4828 & -46.2069 & 11.7241 \\
>  0 & 0 & 11.7241 & -18.6207 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$