# Looping through the internal form of a symbolic expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

Could someone provide code for looping through the internal form for a symbolic expression?

Specifically I am looking to write my own code for simplifying expressions (such as removing a common factor from a vector or matrix) by parsing the internal form of the expression.  I am not satisfied with the results that PolynomialGCD gives.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I fail to understand the question. Can you make the question a bit more specific?

Comment: Any looping you do on an expression is done in a kernel, which always works with the full form of the expression. Any other form is strictly for display.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is does not understand the simple fact that a Mathematica kernel only works on the full form of a Mathematica expression

Comment: According to the answer below, you do misunderstand the usage of `FullForm` in _Mathematica_. In short, there's just no need to use `FullForm` in your code. You may want to read the following post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/1871 Notice the behaviors of `FullForm` and `MatrixForm` are similar here: they just influence the _appearance_ of expression in the notebook.

Comment: I have read it, as I've mentioned in [my last comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195457/looping-through-the-fullform-of-an-expression?noredirect=1#comment508675_195457).

Comment: I also have read your answer and I agree with @xzczd that it shows you fail to be aware that looping over ***any*** expression is looping over its full form because that the only form the kernel doing the looping receives from the front-end.

Comment: @m_goldberg I rewrote the question and the answer that I provided.  I used the verbiage " the internal form of any symbolic expression" from https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/33-expressions-and-their-structure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with to remove a common factor from a vector/list/matrix.  It works *better than PolynomialGCD*.

**First I give an example of usage.**

```
f = {((1 + g)*r^(-1 + g))/E^(r*\[Kappa]), 
   0, (I*r^(-2 + g)*z*\[Alpha])/
    E^(r*\[Kappa]), (I*r^(-2 + g)*(x + I*y)*\[Alpha])/E^(r*\[Kappa])};
Print["ORIGINAL f = ", f // MatrixForm];
With[{cf = PolynomialGCD @@ f}, 
  Print["SIMPLIFIED WITH PolynomialGCD: ", cf, " ", 
   f/cf // MatrixForm]];
PrintRCF["SIMPLIFIED WITH BESPOKE CODE BELOW = ", 
  RemoveCommonFactor[f], ""];
```

**HERE IS THE OUTPUT**
[image]

**Here is the code**

```
RemoveCommonFactor[myexpr_] :=
  Module [{leafcount, atoms, factor, newExpr, Nfactors, depth},
   factor = 1;
   Nfactors = 0;
   newExpr = Simplify[myexpr];
   depth = Depth[newExpr];
   leafcount = LeafCount[newExpr];
   atoms = Union[Flatten[Level[newExpr, 3]]];
   Do[
    Module[ {atom, temp, lc},
     atom = atoms[[i]];
     If[! (atom === 0), (
       temp = Simplify[newExpr/atom];
       lc = LeafCount[temp] +  LeafCount[atom] ;
       If[lc < LeafCount[newExpr] + 1, (
         factor = factor * atom;
         Nfactors = Nfactors + 1;
         newExpr = temp;
         ),
        null
        ];
       )
      ];
     ],
    {i, 1, Length[atoms]}
    ];
   {Nfactors, factor, newExpr}
   ];


PrintRCF[headstr_, rcf_, footstr_] :=
  Module[{Nfactors, myfactor, expr},
   Nfactors = rcf[[1]];
   myfactor = rcf[[2]];
   expr = rcf[[3]];
   If[Nfactors > 0,
    (
     Print[headstr, myfactor, " ", expr // MatrixForm, footstr]
     ),
    (
     Print[headstr, expr // MatrixForm, footstr];
     )
    ];
   Return[null];
   ];
```

Comment: Try `With[{cf = PolynomialGCD @@ f}, Print["f = ", cf," ", f/cf // MatrixForm]]` instead.

Comment: @Somos. Thank you!

Comment: @Somos  Although your code is _immensely_ simpler, my code gives nicer results for a lot of expressions.  An example to try is `{((1 + g)*r^(-1 + g))/E^(r*\[Kappa]), 0, (I*r^(-2 + g)*z*\[Alpha])/E^(r*\[Kappa]), 
   (I*r^(-2 + g)*(x + I*y)*\[Alpha])/E^(r*\[Kappa])}`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be fun for looking at the `FullForm` structure:

````
ff = FullForm[x/Sqrt[5] + y^2 + 1/z] (* example from MMA help *)

(* Plus[1,Times[Power[5,Rational[-1,2]],x],Power[y,2]] *)

t[f_, tree_] := Module[{},
  If[Length[f] == 0, Return[tree],
   Table[(f[[0]] // FullForm) ->
     If[Length[f[[n]]] == 0, f[[n]] // FullForm, t[f[[n]], tree]],
    {n, 1, Length[f]}]]]

t[ff[[1]], {}]

(* {Plus->1,Plus->{Times->{Power->5,Power->Rational[-1,2]},Times->x},Plus->{Power->y,Power->2}} *)

```
````

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will look it over.  I would uptick your answer but my score is too low and I am not yet allowed to do so.