# How to interchange columns of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix

```
M={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}//MatrixForm
```

What code do I write to interchange columns and make it into

```
{{2,3,1},{5,6,4},{8,9,7}}
```

The question mentioned here,
[Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)

does not solve the problem because, I am using //MatrixForm with the list, and it is not working for interchanging columns, while it works for interchanging rows !

Comment: `RotateLeft /@ M`

Comment: `Permute[#,Cycles[{{3,2,1}}]]& /@ M`

Comment: `M[[All, {2, 3, 1}]]`?

Comment: @kglr it interchanges rows not columns. Program is not working for columns !!!

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried methods of the question you posted, it is not working for columns.

Comment: It's there: `m2 = m;
m2[[All, {1, 3}]] = m2[[All, {3, 1}]]` -- instead of `{3, 1}` --> `{1, 3}`, use the permutation of columns you want.  (Note, it's the same as @kglr's comment above.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes I had tried it earlier. However, it did not work. Now, I removed the **//MatrixForm** from the list and it works ! I do not know the reason.

Comment: Yeah, `MatrixForm` does not work like some other "Forms": https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations

Comment: If M is defined with MatrixForm, _maybe_ `newM=M[[1,All,{2,3,1}]]`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods, but the quickest, general one that is easily adjusted for more complicated permutations, is probably:

```
M = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
Map[{#[[2]],#[[3]],#[[1]]}&,M]
```

That is, you take every row of M, and create the list {#[[2]],#[[3]],#[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI6rq.png)]}, where e.g. #[[2]] refers to the second element of the row that is being acted upon.

You can of course also solve this by simple matrix multiplication:

```
A = {{0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0,1,0}}
```

M.A then gives you your requested matrix.

[image]

Comment: Your Map hanges the rows  not the columns I think!

Comment: It changes each row separately to the requested format. Try it, it gives the correct form.

Comment: You're right, but in  the question I read " interchange columns"

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Yes you are right I am not able to interchange columns. I tried a lot of things, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes, and the columns will as a result of the above map function be interchanged. I do not see the issue?

Comment: [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) is a protected symbol in *Mathematica*, you cannot assign values to it.