# Generating all 2x2 matrices with entries from 0 to 3 whose det is 1 with mod 2 arithmetic

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I am trying to make a list of 2x2 matrices whose entries are all possible permutations of 0,1,2 and det=1 mod 2 arithmetic.

First I tried to create a Table like this

```
T1 = Table[{{i, j}, {m, n}}, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2},{m,0,2}]
```

But how to extract it as a list of matrices in `MatrixForm` and including the condition of determinant one?

Comment: I saw that you changed the requirement for the determinant. I added that option to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your `Table` expression, you will want to `Flatten` the results to obtain a list of matrices, rather than nested lists:

```
t1 = Table[{{i, j}, {m, n}}, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}, {m, 0, 2}]~Flatten~3;
```

The same thing can be obtained more directly using `Tuples`:

```
t1 = Tuples[Range[0, 2], {2, 2}]
```

You will then `Select` those matrices that have a unity determinant and apply `MatrixForm` to them individually using `Map`:

```
MatrixForm /@ Select[t1, Det[#] == 1 &]
```

[image: pretty-printed matrices]

---

The question was recently changed to specify that the determinant should be 1 when considered modulo 2. This can be included as well:

```
MatrixForm /@ Select[t1, Mod[Det[#], 2] == 1 &]
```

[image: printed matrices with modulo 2 restriction]

---

It is worth it to add the usual caveat: `MatrixForm` is a formatting wrapper that pretty-prints your matrices, but it will hinder further evaluation; see [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/27951).

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the `Tuples[...,{2,2}]` form to directly obtain the matrices, nice!

Comment: @Thies Yeah, it's pretty handy!

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 2;
sol = Solve[{Mod[a d - b c, 2] == 1, 
    And @@ Thread[0 <= {a, b, c, d} <= n]}, {a, b, c, d}, Integers];

solutions = {{a, b}, {c, d}} /. sol;

Length @ solutions
```

> 16

```
TeXForm @ Grid[Partition[MatrixForm /@ solutions, 4]]
```

> $\begin{array}{cccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2 \\
>  2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  2 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  2 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  2 & 1 \\
>  1 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

For `n = 3` we get

```
Length @ solutions
```

> 96

```
Grid[Partition[MatrixForm /@ solutions, 12]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the mod 2 condition also? I mean to say the det one condition is in modular arithmetic 2. Thanks

Comment: @ricci1729, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One last question .. How to find the number of the total matrics? I used Length but it did not give the result. Please let me know.

Comment: `Length @ sol` or `Length @ solutions`

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't deal with big matrices or big ranges of possible integer entries, i.e. you don't have to fear combinatorial explosion, you can just brute force generate all of them, and then select the proper ones via `Select`:

```
matrices = With[{n = 2, legalmatrixentries = Range[0, 2]}, 
  Select[
    Tuples[legalmatrixentries, {n,n}], 
    OddQ @* Det (* (Mod[Det[#], k] == 1 &) for general modular arithmetic mod k *)
  ]
]
MatrixForm /@ matrices
```

$$
\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\\\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right\}
$$

Related integer sequences:

- Nr. of solutions for the mod2 case: [A210370](https://oeis.org/A210370)
- Nr. of solutions for the non mod2 case: [A171503](https://oeis.org/A171503)

## Updated

- Updated answer to give solutions for modular arithmetic (mod 2)

Comment: You could give multiple dimensions to `Tuples` to get arrays directly, e.g. `Tuples[legalmatrixentries, {n, n}]`, so you can avoid the `Partition`.

Comment: wrong range btw

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for pointing that out, didn't know about it, i like! thanks!

Comment: @Alucard The title and the code example in the OP are not matching, so i just picked the example from the title.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I did a little mistake while making the question... I wish to make the list of matrices with modular arithmetic 2 along with det one condition. I tried Modulus==2 & but it didn't work. Please let me how to incorporate the additional condition. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean to say the det one condition is in modular arithmetic 2.