# Display detail of a function

Tags: matrix

I wrote a function to create and allow loading of a ll x ll upper triangular matrix and would like to see it in detail, matrix elements displayed. Specifically,

```
ME[t_, m] := MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[Table[P[t + 1 - i - m], {i, ll}, {j, ll}]]]
```

where P is another function and ll is a constant allowing changing matrix size externally. Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: `P[v_]:=v;ll=4;ME[t_, m_]:=MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[Table[P[t+1-i-m],{i,ll},{j,ll}]]];ME[2,3]` displays an upper triangular maxtix. Notice I changed `m` to `m_`. Can you reproduce this? What what do you change to make the next small step that does not display correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

Comment: Oops. Closed this for the wrong reason. Nevermind, it was a typo anyways. And the linked post is worth a read anyways.