# Complex Conjugate Transpose of a vector

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex

Suppose that the vector is

```
Psi={{a},{b}};
```

and a and b are imaginary numbers in general. I want to calculate in Mathematica the tensor product
and define a1,b2 as the complex conjugates. I have tried the following

```
(Psi = {{a}, {b}}) // MatrixForm
(Psi1 = MatrixForm[Assuming[{a, b} \[Element] \Complex,Simplify@ConjugateTranspose[Psi]]])
(R=(Psi).(Psi1))//MatrixForm
```

but it doesn't work like i want it to.

P.S.: I want to get  the following result

$$
R=\begin{pmatrix}
\vert{a}\vert^2 & ab^{*}\\
a^{*}b & \vert{b}\vert^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3):

```
ψ = {a, b};
ψ1 = Conjugate[ψ];
R = KroneckerProduct[ψ, ψ1]

(*    {{a*Conjugate[a], a*Conjugate[b]},
       {b*Conjugate[a], b*Conjugate[b]}}    *)

R // TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a a^* & a b^* \\
 b a^* & b b^* \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In Mathematica, there is no concept of row vectors vs. column vectors, so there is no need to transpose (conjugation is enough). [Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.html#22223)

Do not use `MatrixForm` as it [interferes with computation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/26598) (it is only a display wrapper).

Comment: Thank you so much, just what i needed! :)