# Wolfram Mathematica is not showing this matrix operation in matrix form

Tags: matrix

I hope you can help me with this.
I've defined two matrix, i and T, and I want to operate them this way:

[image]

but, as you may see, it simply shows the sum of the two matrices.

I don´t know what could it be.

Comment: Don't use MatrixForm. This is a formatting construct for display purposes.

Comment: It still doesnt work

Comment: You might want to learn how to deal with Matrices. Here is one source: https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch1/matrix.html

Comment: can you post your definitions of `i` and `T`?

Comment: also, what are you looking to achieve here?

Comment: You have to extract the real matrix from the wrapper `MatrixFrom[]`. It is the first part inside : `m1 = MatrixForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]; m2 = 
 MatrixForm[{{x, y}, {z, t}}]; MatrixForm[m1[[1]] + m2[[1]]]`

Comment: Carxs, it will be helpful for others to fully understand your question & be able to help solve your problem, along with improving the experience of future users coming across this QA if you can do what others have commented about re: the definition of `i` and `T`; and it will be especially helpful to be more descriptive of what errors you encounter when you say “It still doesn’t work”.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/4999 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395 (point 8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

Answer (score 2):

You apparently defined `i` and `T` using `MatrixForm`, which makes printable things that aren't matrices for purposes of calculation. Try `MatrixForm[i-T/.MatrixForm->Identity]`. Or, just avoid `MatrixForm` when intending to do calculations with matrices.

Comment: Why would someone (-1) this?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is perfectly reasonable to downvote a question that doesn't post copyable code.  Or a question far larger than necessary:  always post the MINIMUM question.