# How to get the result of a multiplication between a matrix and a scalar?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix,

```
  P = {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 6}}
  ff=6
```

How to do the multiplication of ff with P?
`ff.P` and `ff*P`
are  not working!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "not working"? `ff*P` returns `{{6, 12, 24}, {18, 24, 6}, {12, 6, 36}}` for me, as expected

Comment: Did you use `MatrixForm` in the definition of your matrix? If yes, [then don't](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/26598).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ff.P` does not work because it is a matrix multiplication and clearly `ff` is not such object.

On the other hand, `ff*P` and `P*ff` should work and they do for me.

Note that you can also write `ff P` and `P ff`. Be careful to leave a proper space between them.

The following worked for me as I said already

```
 $Version

"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

P = {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 6}};
ff = 6;
```

And now

```
P*ff // MatrixForm
ff*P // MatrixForm
```

Both of the above expressions result in

[image]