# What kind of method does Solve use to solve a system of overdetermined linear equations?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have a singular homogeneous linear system of equations, which easily can be solved by applying Solve:

```
equs = {x2 == z2, x3 == z3, x5 == z5, w2 == y2,
   w4 == y4, w5 == y5, x1 == y1, x4 == y4,
   x3 == y5, w1 == z1, w4 == z4, w5 == z3,
   x1 == z1, x4 == z4, x5 == z5, w1 == y1,
   w3 == y3, w4 == y4, x2 == y2, x5 == y3,
   x4 == y5, w2 == z2, w3 == z5, w5 == z4};

vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, 
   w1, w2, w3, w4, w5};

Solve[equs, vars]

{{x1 -> w1, x2 -> w2, x3 -> w5, x4 -> w5, x5 -> w3, y1 -> w1, 
  y2 -> w2, y3 -> w3, y4 -> w5, y5 -> w5, z1 -> w1, z2 -> w2, 
  z3 -> w5, z4 -> w5, z5 -> w3, w4 -> w5}}
```

The problem I have is that "Solve" is a "black box" for me. I would like to know the method applied by "Solve" dealing with the kind of equations given above. Is there any other (more specific) method available in Mathematica to deal with these kind of equations?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If WRI wanted to share operational details of a certain functionality they would have done so. They remain in a uniquely advantageous position to comment further on your query. Since this question requires knowledge that only WRI or a professional consultant can provide, I suspect the question would be closed after enough close votes accrue.

Comment: Just to compare. Up to `infolevel[solve] := 4;
solve({w1 = y1, w1 = z1, w2 = y2, w2 = z2, w3 = y3, w3 = z5, w4 = y4, w4 = z4, w5 = y5, w5 = z3, w5 = z4, x1 = y1, x1 = z1, x2 = y2, x2 = z2, x3 = y5, x3 = z3, x4 = y4, x4 = y5, x4 = z4, x5 = y3, x5 = z5}, {w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5});`, Maple uses  linear solver to this end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a null-space solver.

```
equs = {x2 == z2, x3 == z3, x5 == z5, w2 == y2, w4 == y4, w5 == y5,
        x1 == y1, x4 == y4, x3 == y5, w1 == z1, w4 == z4, w5 == z3,
        x1 == z1, x4 == z4, x5 == z5, w1 == y1, w3 == y3, w4 == y4, 
        x2 == y2, x5 == y3, x4 == y5, w2 == z2, w3 == z5, w5 == z4};
```

Let's first convert your equations a bit. Convert to a list of terms that must be zero:

```
zero = equs /. Equal -> Subtract
(*    {x2 - z2, x3 - z3, x5 - z5, w2 - y2, w4 - y4, w5 - y5, x1 - y1,
       x4 - y4, x3 - y5, w1 - z1, w4 - z4, w5 - z3, x1 - z1, x4 - z4,
       x5 - z5, w1 - y1, w3 - y3, w4 - y4, x2 - y2, x5 - y3, x4 - y5,
       w2 - z2, w3 - z5, w5 - z4}                                        *)
```

Extract the list of variables:

```
vars = Sort@Variables[Times @@ zero]
(*    {w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5}    *)
```

Express the equations as a matrix $M$ that, when multiplied by the list of variables, must give a zero vector:

```
M = D[zero, {vars}]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now we know that `M . vars` must give zeros, so `vars` must be a linear combination of vectors from the [null space](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html) of `M`:

```
nullvecs = NullSpace[M]
(*    {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}    *)
```

So any solution vector that is such a linear combination will satisfy the equations:

```
sol = {a, b, c, d} . nullvecs
(*    {d, c, a, b, b, d, c, b, b, a, d, c, a, b, b, d, c, b, b, a}    *)
```

Check:

```
equs /. Thread[vars -> sol]
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
       True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
       True, True, True, True}                                        *)
```

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I wanted :-)

Comment: A slight improvement`M=CoefficientArrays[equs,vars][[2]]//MatrixForm`.

Comment: @user64494 that's not good, see [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/26598)

Comment: I agree with the comment of @Roman regarding MatrixForm. MatrixForm is just a display form and should never be part of a definition. Just as a sidenote: it is easily possible to present the result as a so called "dispatch table" (which is the way "Solve" does present the result): {Table[vars[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sol]}]}. This would be a complete dispatch table while Solve in above case only provides a partial one (together with a corresponding warning: Solve::vars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.)

Comment: @whoever That's exactly what my `Thread[vars -> sol]` does (but without needing to loop explicitly).