# Droping a row from a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to drop a row from a matrix but the output seems to be:

> MatrixForm[]

My code:

```
A = ( {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 800},
{0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 300},
{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 500},
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 600}} );
P = MatrixForm[UpperTriangularize[First[LUDecomposition[A]]]];
Q = Map[Round[#, 0.01] &, P]
Q1 = Drop[Q, 1, None]
```

I am working with a bigger data but to pinpoint my error I used a simple matrix and found I have an issue with using the Drop command. I have tried `Q1 = Drop[Q, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}]`
and other functions like `Delete` and `Part` with no success.

Comment: **[Don't use `MatrixForm[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098)** (except for display purposes).

Comment: Place the variable's definition inside the `MatrixForm` so that `MatrixForm` is not included as part of the definition, i.e., `MatrixForm[P = UpperTriangularize[First[LUDecomposition[A]]]]` or `(P = UpperTriangularize[First[LUDecomposition[A]]]) // MatrixForm`