# Why `MatrixForm` formatting does not work in this context?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, formatting

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_, y_?NumberQ] := x y;
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
$Post = # /. f_[{x__}] :> MatrixFunction[f, {x}] &;
Sqrt[( {
    {-1, 0},
    {0, -1}
   } )] // MatrixForm
```

The output comes in list form, not as a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the last 2 lines to reproduce the issue, and the last 2 lines can be further simplified to

```
$Post = # /. f_[{x__}] :> aaa[f, {x}] &;
{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}} // MatrixForm
(* aaa[MatrixForm, {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}] *)
```

As we can see, the rule in `$Post` is executed later than `MatrixForm` i.e. the code above is amount to

```
$Post =.;
{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}} // MatrixForm // (# /. f_[{x__}] :> aaa[f, {x}] &)
```

This is consistent with the description in [the document of `$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html):

> `$Post` is a global variable whose value, if set, is applied to every output expression.

See also the introduction in the tutorial [*The Main Loop*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GlobalAspectsOfWolframSystemSessions.html#13888).

Comment: Is there a way to format the output as a matrix?

Comment: @Anixx Of course, just move the `MatrixForm` to `$Post`, too. (Alternatively, `$PrePrint`. ) See this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3098/1871

Comment: Moving it to $Post does not work for me.

Comment: @Anixx How do you move it?

Comment: `$Post = ReleaseHold[Hold[#] /. f_[{x__}] :> MatrixFunction[f, {x}]]//MatrixForm &;`

Comment: @Anixx Click on `MatrixForm` three times, and you'll see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the full form your your evaluated expression:

Sqrt[({{-1, 0}, {0, -1}})] // MatrixForm //FullForm

[image]

This matches your pattern:

```
 f_[{x__}]
```

With  f == MatrixForm and {x_} == {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}

Therefore, the matrix representation is changed into:

```
MatrixFunction[Sqrt, {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}]
```

and this evaluates into:

```
{{I, 0}, {0, I}}
```

Comment: "With f == Sqrt and {x_} == {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}" Clearly not. The `Sqrt` is no longer there.

Comment: (-1) The answer is still incorrect after edit.