# Mathematica not taking inverse or transpose of matrix

Tags: matrix

[image: Code provided from file with the issue I am having]

I am trying to take the transpose and inverse of ThreeA, but the output isn't performing this command for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: See [this previous thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/). In short: get rid of `MatrixForm[]` and it should work.